# Как один из столбцов в существующем DataFrame использовать в качестве названия столбцов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5, dataframe

Есть пример существующего датафрейма. Мне нужно использовать один из его столбцов в качестве названия столбцов. Как это сделать?

**Пример исходного датафрейма:**

```html
x = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5],  [7,1,3,6,7,9])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x**2+8, "B": x*8, "C": x+34, "D": (x*x)+5, "E": (x*2)+5, "F": (2**x-x), 'idx':[2,0,1,8,2,3]})
```

Вот что я хочу сделать. Из столбца `idx` получить все значения и использовать их в качестве названия столбцов. А затем сам столбец удалить, чтобы матрица осталась квадратной.

**Смотрите наглядный скрин:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.set_axis(df.pop('idx'), axis='columns', inplace=False)
```

или

```
df.columns = df.pop('idx')
```

В обоих случаях результат будет следующим:

```
In [112]: df
Out[112]:
idx   2   0   1   8   2   3
7     9   8  35   6   7   1
1    24  32  38  21  13  12
3    17  24  37  14  11   5
6    12  16  36   9   9   2
7     9   8  35   6   7   1
9    33  40  39  30  15  27
```